# C# RSA Encryption using iOS generated Public Key

Tags: c#, ios, encryption, rsa

I trying to set up RSA Encryption channel between iOS and C#.

In iOS public key is generated using Security Framework.

Code Snippet,

```
NSData* tag = [@"com.x.x.x" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* attributes =
    @{ (id)kSecAttrKeyType:               (id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
       (id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits:         @1024,
       (id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs:
           @{ (id)kSecAttrIsPermanent:    @YES,
              (id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag,
              },
       };

    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    SecKeyRef privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes,
                                                 &error);
    if (!privateKey) {
        NSError *err = CFBridgingRelease(error); 
        // Handle the error. . .
    }

    SecKeyRef publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey);
```

Result: `"MIGJAoGBAMIt95f4xaP7vYV/+Hdyb4DK0oKvw495PrRYG3nsYgVP7zlBE/rTN6Nmt69W9d0nGefuRlJFIr9TA8vlJmqTus6uXEasBuEjzH7vM7HQeAK6i8qEbVy0T+Uuq+16yy059NL7i/VWljVE6rqTntDUELmbIwNBwj6oBuL1z3SnFoMjAgMBAAE="`

In C# I am trying to use the above generated public key in order to encrypt the data.

C# Code Snippet:

```
const string pKey = "MIGJAoGBAMIt95f4xaP7vYV/+Hdyb4DK0oKvw495PrRYG3nsYgVP7zlBE/rTN6Nmt69W9d0nGefuRlJFIr9TA8vlJmqTus6uXEasBuEjzH7vM7HQeAK6i8qEbVy0T+Uuq+16yy059NL7i/VWljVE6rqTntDUELmbIwNBwj6oBuL1z3SnFoMjAgMBAAE=";
            byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pKey);              
            var stream = new MemoryStream(publicKeyBytes);
            Asn1Object asn1Object = Asn1Object.FromStream(stream);
```

I am evaluating the `asn1Object` and manually copying the `Modulus` and `Exponent` which in this case is,

```
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger("136357523654993073600337541886612209461653649830596179928022807129764638978058775447065286245685299741061442447812373893408612622888251899821604061796495147997132112844250946475016809624300789149318149170549447812758865778797994482272574020014042899233361299524505365746896235948770695552862804390518105473827");
            BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger("65537");
```

And then I am able to generate Public Key using,

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter param = new RsaKeyParameters(false, modulus, exponent);
 RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)param;
            RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
 rsaParameters.Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
            rsaParameters.Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();  
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
```

Q1. Is there any way to iterate through the ans1Object and get the corresponding data?

Q2. Is there any way to directly use the iOS generated Base64(public key) in the C#?

Q3. I need to send the public key in the same format back to the client.

P.S. Any guidance and help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So SO SO,

After so many research and 100s of stack overflow tabs.

I am able to use the iOS Generated Public key in the C# for encryption using Bouncy castle.

```
pkey : Public Key given from client
```

Code Snippet Below:

```
            const string pKey = "MIGJAoGBAMIt95f4xaP7vYV/+Hdyb4DK0oKvw495PrRYG3nsYgVP7zlBE/rTN6Nmt69W9d0nGefuRlJFIr9TA8vlJmqTus6uXEasBuEjzH7vM7HQeAK6i8qEbVy0T+Uuq+16yy059NL7i/VWljVE6rqTntDUELmbIwNBwj6oBuL1z3SnFoMjAgMBAAE=";
            byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pKey);

            var stream = new MemoryStream(publicKeyBytes);
            Asn1Object asn1Object = Asn1Object.FromStream(stream);
            Asn1Encodable asn1Sequence = asn1Object;   

            AlgorithmIdentifier algorithmIdentifier = new 
            AlgorithmIdentifier(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.IdRsaesOaep);  

            SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo = new 
            SubjectPublicKeyInfo(algorithmIdentifier, asn1Sequence);   

            AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter2 = 
            PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(subjectPublicKeyInfo);    

            RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = 
            (RsaKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter2;
            RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
            rsaParameters.Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
            rsaParameters.Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
            string test = "John snow is the true king";
            byte[] encbyte = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
            string encrt = Convert.ToBase64String(encbyte);
```

P.S. The code is not very optimized as of now so please ignore that.